# how to implement pagination in dojox.datagrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojo.gridx

i have a req of displaying pagination in the dojox.datagrid i tried searching but no luck. Wanted to know whether  pagination is possible in dojox.datagrid Can some one confirm this please.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Pagination");
```

In your grid

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px',

        plugins: {
          pagination: {
              pageSizes: ["25", "50", "100", "All"],
              description: true,
              sizeSwitch: true,
              pageStepper: true,
              gotoButton: true,
                      /*page step to be displayed*/
              maxPageStep: 4,
                      /*position of the pagination bar*/
              position: "bottom"
          }
        }
    }, document.createElement('div'));
```

Comment: I am using dojox.datagrid ,you given solution for enhanced grid. Can you proivde solution for datagrid ?